# Tax treatment in India on a Resident Indian on money he earned in UAE as NRI earlier

Tags: taxes, investing, india, income

I worked in UAE from Sept'2006 to Mar'2014 and came back to India permanently on April'2014. Before returning to India, I invested some amount in USD dominated bonds through a local bank in UAE on Mar'2014.

Now I have come out of bonds and parked the amount in the same bank in UAE. Now I need the money in India and want to bring that money to India through bank transfer. What is tax implication for me on that amount in India in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to speak withe a Charted Accountant, but I believe that you will only have to pay taxes on the capital gains. This will be treated like a non listed security.  I hope that you have declared this money previously a foreign asset in your tax returns.
Anyway the right answer is speak to a CA